# Confusion related to HMM

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

I was reading this book related to Pattern Recognition and Machine learning by Bishop. However, I have a confusion related to a derivation

[image]

In the book when they calculate the marginal posterior of the hidden variables, I am ok up to.

But in the page attached, I am confused what they mean by conditional probability of $z_{nk} = 1$ and they have

$\gamma(z_{nk}) = \sum_{z}\gamma(z) z_{nk}$ what does z signify here?

Lets say I have an example with z=[z1...zN] does that mean expectation over all possible combination of z lets say I have 3 possible values for each latent variable. So it means N^3 is it?

I am confused any clarifications?

Also I am confused about the maximization part

During maximization they calculate the $\pi_{k}$ as

$\pi_{k} = \frac{\gamma(z_{1k})}{\sum_{j=1}^{K} \gamma{z_{(1j)}}}$. Isn't the sum of the lower part equal to 1? So it doesn't change anything. Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Each latent variable $\mathbf{z}_n$ has $K$ values, say... I have the feeling that $z_{nk}$ might represent just a simple vector like $(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ where the $1$ is at the $k$-th position. That would somewhat explain the equation because on both sides we just have $\gamma(z_{nk}) = p(\mathbf{z}_n = k|\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{\theta^{\text{old}}})$ then... could that be? I think he just wants to express the probability that $\mathbf{x_n}$ belongs to class $k$ in a very quirky way. Edit: Oops, this question is probably already dead :-)